# Using Canon MX535 with 18.04

Tags: canon

After adding a Canon MX535 printer to my devices, the printer shows up as Canon_MX530_series, but the printer status shows up as "Printer does not accept jobs". When I print a document, LibreOffice says "Print complete" but I get no output. The status stays at "Printer does not accept jobs". What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

-Additional Printer Properties.
-Printer properties
-Device URI - Network Printer - select your printer

- Also check Policies, make sure Enabled and Accepts Jobs are ticked

Answer (score 0):

adding rolfbensch ppa (https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git) and some deb

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp libsane libsane-extras libsane-common
```

I had to reinstall libsane and libsane-common because of a problem with a configuration file, the same problem appeared on 3 computers with different configuration

Now everything works perfectly

PS:I have kept this page up to date for a few years -> https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/26540